# core-count tasks CompletableFuture slower than parallelStream

Tags: java, parallel-processing, java-stream, completable-future, forkjoinpool

My PC is four-cored (FYI)

CompletableFuture will use `ForkJoinPool.commonPool()` as its [official doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html) points out:

> All async methods without an explicit Executor argument are performed using the ForkJoinPool.commonPool() (unless it does not support a parallelism level of at least two, in which case, a new Thread is created to run each task).

I debugged and found out the following code from `CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(Supplier<U> supplier)`

```
private static final boolean useCommonPool =
    (ForkJoinPool.getCommonPoolParallelism() > 1);

/**
 * Default executor -- ForkJoinPool.commonPool() unless it cannot
 * support parallelism.
 */
private static final Executor asyncPool = useCommonPool ?
    ForkJoinPool.commonPool() : new ThreadPerTaskExecutor();
```

Which means as `parallelStream` always does using `ForkJoinPool.commonPool()`, but here why it's quicker.

I tried to print them out and found out that only **three** threads when using CompletableFuture:

```
private static int concurrencyGet() {
    List<CompletableFuture<Integer>> futureList = IntStream.rangeClosed(0, 10).boxed()
   .map(i -> CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> getNumber(i)))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    return futureList.stream().map(future -> future.join()).reduce(0, Integer::sum);
}
```

But parallelStream using **four** including the **main** thread.

My guess is that in `CompletableFuture.supplyAsync()`, the `ForkJoinPool.getCommonPoolParallelism()` is only **three** while main thread taking one of the four, since it's **asynchronous**.

But the **parallelStream** will use up all the **four** since its not **asynchronous**.

Is this correct? I wonder are there some official documentations for this issue?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: I do not understand what you are trying to compare. `Stream`s are for processing a (potentially unlimited) series of elements, while `CompletableFuture` is for (asynchronuous) processing of a single piece of data...

Comment: @MarkusMitterauer I am just curious about it and search for the support but nothing comes up to prove to it officially. It's natural for me to compare **sequentiality**, **parallelism(parallelStream)** and **Asynchrony(CompletableFuture)**, since they're working quite different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Following is how I understood it from **Venkat Subramaniam**s talk on [Parallel and Asynchronous Programming with Streams and CompletableFuture](https://youtu.be/0hQvWIdwnw4):*

As `CompleteableFuture` also utilizes `ForkJoinPool.commonPool()` it  may as well use the main thread, and it does under certain circumstances.

Given the following example

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    CompletableFuture<Integer> future = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> numberSupplier());
    future.thenAccept(i -> System.out.println("f: " + i + " - " + Thread.currentThread()));
    sleep(100); //wait for async operations to finish before exiting
}

private static Integer numberSupplier() {
    Integer n = 2;
    System.out.println("c: " + n + " - " + Thread.currentThread());
    sleep(19);
    return n;
}

private static void sleep(int millis) {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(millis);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

you might get a console output like this:

```
c: 2 - Thread[ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1,5,main]
f: 2 - Thread[ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1,5,main]
```

Both, the `supplyAsync(..)` as well as the `thenAccept(..)` part are executed by a worker thread from the `ForkJoinPool`.

However, if the `Supplier<Integer>` given to `supplyAsync(..)` is so fast, that it is finished when the `thenAccept(..)` is invoked, then that second part might as well be executed in the main thread:

```
private static Integer numberSupplier() {
    Integer n = 2;
    //System.out.println("c: " + n + " - " + Thread.currentThread());
    //sleep(19);
    return n;
}
```

Output:

```
f: 2 - Thread[main,5,main]
```

Comment: You are creating two operations, one depending on the other, and as a consequence, one operation is performed after the other. Whether the second operation uses the pool thread or the main thread is entirely irrelevant here, as in either case, the outcome is that your example code uses exactly one thread at a time and no parallelism. What is that supposed to prove?